# ObjectInputStream returns ObjectStreamClass

Tags: java, serialization, stream, network-programming

I'm having a bit of trouble. The following line executes fine on client on first read, but fails on second read.

WorkerNode.java:72 `Message task = (Message) in.readObject();`

in is a private ObjectInputStream. The exception received is the following

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.ObjectStreamClass cannot be cast to parallelprogramming.Message
    at parallelprogramming.WorkerNode.receiveTask(WorkerNode.java:72)
    at parallelprogramming.WorkerNode.computeTillEndOfWork(WorkerNode.java:139)
    at parallelprogramming.Worker.main(Worker.java:24)
Nov 15, 2014 11:07:15 PM parallelprogramming.WorkerNode receiveTask
SEVERE: null
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1379)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at parallelprogramming.WorkerNode.receiveTask(WorkerNode.java:72)
    at parallelprogramming.WorkerNode.lambda$startListeningForWork$0(WorkerNode.java:59)
    at parallelprogramming.WorkerNode$$Lambda$1/798154996.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Exception in thread "WorkListener" java.lang.ClassCastException: parallelprogramming.MatMulTask cannot be cast to parallelprogramming.Message
    at parallelprogramming.WorkerNode.receiveTask(WorkerNode.java:72)
    at parallelprogramming.WorkerNode.lambda$startListeningForWork$0(WorkerNode.java:59)
    at parallelprogramming.WorkerNode$$Lambda$1/798154996.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Java Result: 1
```

Message has the following structure.

```
public class Message implements IMessage{
    private final MessageType type;
    private final Object payload;
```

IMessage extends Serializable. I'm using the same ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream in both client and server side. I tried searching around but to no luck. Anyone else found something similar?

EDIT2:
Code that sends Message to Worker:

```
private final Map<String, WorkerConn> nodes;
//nodes initialized in constructor
private void sendTaskToNode(ITask task, String node) {
        if(task == null){
            return;
        }        
        try{   
            Message msg = new Message(MessageType.task, task);
            nodes.get(node).sendObject(msg);

            nodes.get(node).incrementworkCount();

            System.out.println("Sent work to "+node);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MasterNode.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Send object in WorkerConn:

```
public WorkerConn(Socket socket, String name) throws IOException {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        this.in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        this.name = name;
        workCount = 0;
    }

void sendObject(Message msg) throws IOException {
        out.writeObject(msg);
    }
```

The part that receives Message on Worker:

```
public void receiveTask() throws NotConnectedToMasterException {
        try {
            Message task = (Message) in.readObject();
            if(task.getMessageType() == MessageType.task){
                tasks.add((ITask) task.getPayload());
                System.out.println("Received Task");
            }else if(task.getMessageType() == MessageType.endOfWork){
                ITask t = new AbstractTask() {

                    @Override
                    public Object call() throws Exception {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                    }
                };
                t.setDeathPill();
                tasks.add(t);
                System.out.println("added deathpill");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Received "+task.getMessageType());
            }
        } catch(EOFException ex) {
            return;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WorkerNode.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WorkerNode.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

EDIT:
Found my problem. I was creating a thread to listen for incoming tasks, reading the input stream, and was also reading the same input stream from main thread when task queue was empty. In Worker node:

```
private void startListeningForWork(){
        workListener = new Thread(() -> {
            while(!master.isClosed()){
                try {
                    receiveTask();
                } catch (NotConnectedToMasterException ex) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
        workListener.setName("WorkListener");
        workListener.start();
    }
```

and

```
while(!task.isDeathPill()){
            try {                
                results.addToResult(task.call());
                sendACKtoMaster();                
                task = tasks.remove();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                try {
                    receiveTask();
                } catch (NotConnectedToMasterException ex1) {
                    Logger.getLogger(WorkerNode.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
                    break;
                }
            }   
        }
```

That was causing one of the threads to read the object before the other and mess things up.

Comment: Show where you send the data as well

Comment: uploaded the whole code to github. link at the end of the post

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not going to look through all those files for the single `writeObject` statement that correlates with that specific `readObject` statement (especially since I'm on a phone). At least tell me which class in which package

Comment: sorry about that. Message is sent here https://github.com/kalgecin/parallelProgrammingTest/blob/master/src/parallelprogramming/MasterNode.java#L145

Comment: didn't go through it in detail, but i'm pretty sure you have some synchronization issues.  the WorkerNode uses the nodes map in a thread-unsafe manner.  i didn't fully analyze the worker, but my guess is that you are not correctly synchronizing access to your streams.

Comment: The server creates one thread to handle each node after accept. So only one thread accesses each of the sockets streams. And the error above occurs with one connected worker. I've tried and searched, but can't see more than one thread accessing input or output stream at once.

Comment: Code that forms part of a question must be posted *here,* in the question. It it's long you must reduce it to a short example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @EJP Added. Sorry, I'm new to posting to stackoverflow. Trying my best

Comment: What does the `sendObject()` method look like?

Comment: I included it in the WorkerConn above. It just does writeObject

Comment: Sorry for bothering you guys. Found my problem. Was reading from output stream on two threads :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my problem. I was creating a thread to listen for incoming tasks, reading the input stream, and was also reading the same input stream from main thread when task queue was empty. In Worker node:

```
private void startListeningForWork(){
        workListener = new Thread(() -> {
            while(!master.isClosed()){
                try {
                    receiveTask();
                } catch (NotConnectedToMasterException ex) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
        workListener.setName("WorkListener");
        workListener.start();
    }
```

and

```
while(!task.isDeathPill()){
            try {                
                results.addToResult(task.call());
                sendACKtoMaster();                
                task = tasks.remove();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                try {
                    receiveTask();
                } catch (NotConnectedToMasterException ex1) {
                    Logger.getLogger(WorkerNode.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
                    break;
                }
            }   
        }
```

That was causing one of the threads to read the object before the other and mess things up.

Comment: As @jtahlborn predicted.

Comment: yeah :) debugged every line before i found it :( java needs better explanations in exceptions for this kind of stuff :p or better handle races